# Different definition for L smooth function.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, hessian-matrix, smooth-functions

At optimization class, professor gave the definition of L smooth function by

$f:\mathbf{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $ is L smooth if all the eigenvalue for $\nabla^{2} f $ is smaller than L

where $\nabla^{2} f = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1} & \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 } & \cdots & \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_n } 
\\ \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots 
\\  \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_n \partial x_1} & \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_n \partial x_2 } & \cdots & \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_n \partial x_n } 
\end{pmatrix}$

but when I search for other books, it state that

$f$ is L smooth if $ \frac{\lVert \nabla f(x)- \nabla f(y)\rVert}{\lVert x-y \rVert} \leq L,$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbf{R^n}$

Are these two statement equivalent ?

What I have done is
$ \frac{\lVert \nabla f(x)- \nabla f(y)\rVert}{\lVert x-y \rVert} \leq L,$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbf{R^n}$  $\implies$ $\lvert \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \rvert \leq L, \forall i,j$, but I don't know how it relate to the eigenvalue of $\nabla^2f$.

Later the professor had this

$f(x^t)-f(x^*)=\frac{1}{2}(x^t-x^*)^T\nabla^2f(\bar{x})^T(x^t-x^*)\leq \frac{L}{2}\lVert x^t-x^* \rVert^2$

where $x\in \mathbf{R^n},$ $x^t$ is t iteration for x, $x^*$ is the final form of $x$ s.t. $f(x^*)$ smallest, $\bar{x}$ is some point between $x^t$ and $x^*$.

This part $f(x^t)-f(x^*)=\frac{1}{2}(x^t-x^*)^T\nabla^2f(\bar{x})^T(x^t-x^*)$ is by Tyler expansion which I can understand

The second inequation
$\frac{1}{2}(x^t-x^*)^T\nabla^2f(\bar{x})^T(x^t-x^*)\leq \frac{L}{2}\lVert x^t-x^* \rVert^2$ is where I don't get it. Is it by the definition professor stated for L smooth ?

Comment: *How* is this a [tag:linear-algebra] question?

Comment: Because it relate to eigenvalue. Shouldn't it be?

Comment: I think that it's more a [tag:real-analysis] question than a [tag:linear-algebra] one. I've added more tags. Do you agree with them?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When the function $f$ is convex and twice differentiable, the following are equivalent:

1. $\frac{L}{2}\|\cdot\|^2-f(\cdot)\quad$ is a convex function
2. $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$
3. $0\leq \nabla^2 f(x)\leq L \mathrm{Id}\quad$    (where inequalities are understood in the Loewner ordering and $\mathrm{Id}$ denoted the identity matrix)

The last inequality you're interested in follows directly from 3., the inequality means for any $d$,

$$0\leq \langle d, \nabla^2f(x) d\rangle \leq \frac{L}{2}\|d\|^2$$

Comment: Is there a typo in your formula 3? I suspect the $d$ should be deleted

Comment: I use $\mathrm{Id}$ to represent the identity, it's not $Id$. I added a note to make it clearer.

Comment: I guess then the original question is: Are 2 and 3 equivalent, even if $f$ is not necessarily convex? The other answer shows 3 implies 2 always.

Comment: It's straightforward to show that 2 implies 3 by taking $y=x+\epsilon s$ and taking the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice first that if all the eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f$ are smaller than $L$ then $\|(\nabla^2 f)(x) v\| \leq L\|v\|$ for any $x,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Pick two points $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\gamma :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a straight curve from $x$ to $y$. Using a variant of the fundamental theorem of calculus, some inequalities, and that the length of $\gamma$ is exactly the distance between $x$ and $y$, we get:
$$
\begin{split}\|(\nabla f)(y) - (\nabla f)(x)\| 
&= \left\|\int_0^1 (\nabla^2f)(\gamma(t))\dot\gamma(t)\ dt \right\| \\
&\leq \int_0^1 \|(\nabla^2f)(\gamma(t))\dot\gamma(t)\|\ dt\\ 
&\leq \int_0^1 L \|\dot\gamma(t)\|\ dt\\
&= L \|x - y\|
\end{split}
$$
This at least shows that the one implies the other :).